# Merge two unallocated partition using gparted?

Tags: system-installation, gparted, unallocated

I am having a trouble in merging two unallocated partition. Can anyone help me with this?

The problem that I found different is, the unallocated partition seems to be inside the `/dev/sda3`.

[image: image of my partition]

Comment: You won't be able to merge those without moving around the partitions, and that will be very time-consuming.

Comment: Why not just expand the two ntfs partitions to fill those unallocated space?

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that they can't be merged because they are not next to each other. Try moving sda 5 and sda 4 all the way to the left or right so the unallocated areas are next to each other and see if you can merge them then.

Good luck.